# How to make HTML+CSS tooltip appear on top (avoid clip)?

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I am trying to create a simple tooltip using just HTML+CSS. Here is what I have:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>some text</span>
    <span id="tooltip">some (1) longer (2) text (3)...</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

span#tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: -10em;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: 1000;
}

div:hover span#tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

Unfortunately, the tooltip gets clipped. How to make it appear on top of everything?

http://jsfiddle.net/z9seu/

It gets clipped in this jsfiddle, in my case that is in a table in a div whatever, and gets clipped also.

Thanks!

Comment: [Tooltipster](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=tooltipster&safe=off) can help make your life easier

Comment: Even if your problem is solved, your tooltip won't work on touchscreens. If you would be interested in a light-weight HTML/CSS/Javascript (native/vanilla) tooltip, fully customizable and still very intuitive, let me know and I'll post the code. Also, you should add the `tooltip` tag to your question.

Comment: @FrankConijn: sure post it! Why is this tooltip not going to work on touchscreens? Is it possible for a pure HTML+CSS tooltip to work on touchscreens?

Comment: Because there is no mouse cursor and thus no `:hover` on touchscreens. For a tooltip to work (through `onclick` or `onmousedown`) on those screens, you need a bit of Javascript. See my answer, particularly the demo.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is with your

```
left: -10em;
```

If you remove that line (or make it a positive value), the full length of your text appears.

Since you are making it absolute, it moves it out of the screen.

Comment: This is intentional! I want to position the tooltip relative to the parent `div`.

Comment: Can you make the JSFiddle exactly what you are trying to do then?

Comment: Well, my real case is somewhat complicated because the tooltip is embedded in `div`s structure (page layout) and in a `table`. It will be sufficient if you make this jsfiddle tooltip appear on top of everything else.

Comment: In that JSFiddle it IS appearing on top of everything else.

Comment: It is clipped in my Iceweasel. :(

Comment: What part is clipped.  The only part tat is "clipped" is the part that comes before the edge of the webpage which will not show because as stated it is OUT OF BOUNDS OF the document

Comment: Perhaps submit a screencap

Comment: The clipped part (fails to display) is this: "some (1) longer (2".

Comment: In the JSFiddle that portion is off the edge of the screen.

Comment: The way JSFiddle works is by creating an iframe.  You will not see something that is negatively positioned relative to the entire page

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments under the question, a light-weight HTML + CSS + (vanilla/native) Javascript tooltip that should solve the OP's problem, and work on touchscreens at the same time. Here is the [**live demo**](http://jsbin.com/nerul/5/edit?html,output).

And this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Light-weight Tooltip by FC</title>
<style>
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
    font: normal 1.3em Verdana;
    background-color: white; /* just for the JSBin demo */
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
span.tool {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}
span.tool:hover {
    cursor: help;
}
span.tip {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: .9em;
    border: 0px solid black; /* change as desired */
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    background: #eee;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#eee), to(#ccc));
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eee, #ccc);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr=#eeeeee,EndColorStr=#cccccc);
    zoom: 1;
    visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Light-weight Tooltip by FC</h2>

    <p>The <span class="tool">WHO<span class="tip">World Health Organization</span></span> was established in 1948.</p>

    <p>
        It is part of the
        <span class="tool">UN
            <span class="tip">United Nations, <br>the successor of the <br>League of Nations</span>
        </span>,
        which was established in 1945.
    </p>

    <hr>

    <p>Explanation and 'minds':</p>

    <ul>
        <li>The method consists of local nested spans ('tools' with 'tips' inside), positioned relative-absolute.</li>
        <li>If the same tips are to be used several times throughout the page or website, the tip spans can be populated centrally with Javascript or server-side scripting.</li>
        <li>In the current code the width of the tips is set to <i>auto</i>, and controlled with &lt;br&gt;s in the tip text. Change to fixed width as desired.</li>
        <li>With the current code tablet users must tap (= <i>onclick</i>) rather than press-hold (= <i>onmousedown</i>). It is assumed that that is the intuitive thing most tablet users do, but it can be changed to press-hold.</li>
        <li>The HTML is valid and the code works in IE8 as well.</li>
        <li>It is said that <i>getElementsByClassName(class)</i> returns a dynamic node list, whereas <i>querySelectorAll(.class)</i> would return a static one. That would make the latter unsuited for dynamically updated elements/sections. Also, it is said to be slower/require more CPU power than the first. However, <i>querySelectorAll(.class)</i> is supported by IE8 (not 7). Mind the dot.</li>
        <li>For the sake of completeness: IE9 does not form a border-radius when the element has no declared border, or a border-width of 0.</li>
    </ul>

<script>
// Primer script to make IE8 support getElementsByClassName:
if (!document.getElementsByClassName) {
    document.getElementsByClassName = function(theClass) {
        var elemArray = [];
        var elems = this.getElementsByTagName('*');
        for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
            var allClasses = elems[i].className;
            var classRegex = new RegExp('^('+theClass+')$|(\\s'+theClass+'\\b)');
            // pattern demo on http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hhswl?editors=100
            if (classRegex.test(allClasses) == true)
                elemArray.push(elems[i]);
        }
        return elemArray;
    }
}
// End primer script


var tools = document.getElementsByClassName('tool');
for (var i=0; i<tools.length; i++) {
    var tool = tools[i];
    if ('ontouchstart' in window || (window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch)) {
        tool.onclick = function() {
            if (this.children[0].style.visibility == '' || this.children[0].style.visibility == 'hidden')
                this.children[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
            else 
                this.children[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
    else {
        tool.onmouseover = function() {
            this.children[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        tool.onmouseout = function() {
            this.children[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

.
If matters are not fully self-explanatory (after some study...), just let me know via a comment.